# User-specific fields in simple-schema/AutoForm collection insert [Meteor]

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteorite

Im using a simple-schema and a quickForm to allow users to persist documents to my collection,  but I want to add `Meteor.userId()` and `Meteor.user().username` fields to ultimately only return data specific to the current user.  Since quickForms doesnt show its `insert()` method, Im not sure where to add the fields.

Below is the schema I am using to allow a user to persist `Speakers` to the collection.

```
    Speakers = new Meteor.Collection('speakers');

    Speakers.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
            first: {
                type: String,
                label: "first name",
                max: 200
            },

            last: {
                type: String,
                label: "last name",
                max: 200
            },

            date: {
                type: Date,
                label: 'date',
                optional: true
            }
    }));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm understanding you correctly, but why not

```
Speakers.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
        first: {
            type: String,
            label: "first name",
            max: 200
        },

        last: {
            type: String,
            label: "last name",
            max: 200
        },

        date: {
            type: Date,
            label: 'date',
            optional: true
        },
        userId: {
            type: String
        }
}));
```

Use [autovalue](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#autovalue) if you would like to auto fill based on the user that is inserting the record

To use quickForm and not show the userId field you can do the following

```
{{> quickForm collection="Speakers" id="speakerForm" type="insert" omitFields="userId"}}
```

Comment: you are understanding the question correctly--is the autovalue then a helper for my schema?

Comment: if I add the `userId` field to my quickForm schema, `userId` then shows up as a field in my form submission, though.

Comment: Generally quickForm is great for getting started, but if you want more flexibility you can user the individual methods.

quickForm can still be used via the omitFields attribute.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to omit some of the fields from input form and populate those fields with value yourself, you can use afQuickField with a before hook.

First, add the userId and username fields to your schema.

```
{{#autoForm collection=speakerCollection id="speakerForm" type="insert"}}
    {{> afQuickField name="first"}}
    {{> afQuickField name="last"}}
    {{> afQuickField name="date"}}
<div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
</div>
{{/autoForm}}
```

You need to add a helper to return the speakerCollection

```
Template.registerHelper("speakerCollection", Speakers);
```

Then add a before hook to add the userId:

```
AutoForm.hooks({
  speakerForm: {
    before: {
      "insert": function (doc) {
        doc.userId = Meteor.userId();
        return doc;
      },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `autoValue` to define automatically inserted values:

```
Speakers = new Meteor.Collection('speakers');

Speakers.attachSchema(new SimpleSchema({
    userId: {
        type: String,
        autoValue: function() {
            return Meteor.user()._id;
        }
    },
    author: {
        type: String,
        autoValue: function() {
            return Meteor.user().username;
        }
    },
}));
```

In case you want to omit some fields in the autoform, you can set `autoform.omit = true`:

```
userId: {
    type: String,
    autoValue: function() {
        return Meteor.user()._id;
    },

    // omit the userId field in autoform forms
    autoform: {
        omit: true
    }
}
```